# WPF performance: resetting source of Image controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance, imagesource

I am using the AForge.NET library to acquire image data from my webcam periodically. For debugging reasons, I have to draw out the filtered images to the screen. 
Currently I have 6 WPF Images on my main form, and on every second I handle an event which gives me an UnmanagedImage which I convert into System.Drawing.Bitmap and then to BitmapSource - my code looks something like this:

```
private void OnImageFiltered(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    var bitmapSource = e.UnmanagedImage.ToManagedImage().ToBitmapSource();
    pictureBox.Source = bitmapSource;
}
```

But as I said before, I have 6 Images, and it slows the whole program down.
How can I make it faster?

My ToBitmapSource extension method is here:

```
public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(this System.Drawing.Image source)
{
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(source);

    var bitSrc = bitmap.ToBitmapSource();

    bitmap.Dispose();
    bitmap = null;

    return bitSrc;
}
```

Comment: I believe `bitmap.ToBitmapSource()` is the most costly component, here, however you can likely save a small amount of overhead using the bool parameter constructor, as `var bitmapSource = e.UnmanagedImage.ToManagedImage(false).ToBitmapSource();`. Since it is event-driven, it is likely already happening on a background thread, correct?

Comment: The whole thing (I mean the event handler code) is inside a Dispatcher.Invoke with DispatcherPriority.Send, because it's running on the background thread.

Comment: So I would be interested in what is the "best practice" to solve problems like this? For example drawing out 6 webcams in a single WPF form? Maybe I do this completely wrong with resetting the image sources...

Comment: Processing the image in the background won't make the program any "faster", but it will make it appear more responsive. Try to get the `BitmapSource` in the background thread, then only set `pictureBox.Source` through the `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

Comment: But when I call the ToBitmapSource on the background thread, I get an error: "The calling thread cannot access this object* because a different thread owns it"
(*the object is the BitmapSource object which is an InteropBitmap in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for writing an answer, but I can't comment yet because of my low reputation.

If the problem still persists, use the `Freeze` method to make the BitmapSource readonly and therefor passable to a different thread.